# Proving the statement $A\setminus(A\setminus B)=B\setminus(B\setminus A)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove/disprove the following statement:

$$A \setminus (A \setminus B) = B \setminus (B \setminus A)$$

From what I gather, it is true, since a simple venn diagram check suggests the two are the same. 
However, I am stuck on how to prove it.

**Note**: I am also given the following equalities to use in my proof:

$$A \setminus B = A \cap B^\complement$$
$$(A \setminus B)^\complement = A^\complement \cup B$$

So far, I have tried converting the first part of the original statement using the given equalities into the following: $$ A \cap (A^\complement \cup B) $$ but I have no idea if I'm on the right path. I can't seem to find out how to show that the two are subsets of one another.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: you can distribute the intersection in your last statement

Comment: Yes. Then you'll find that both sides equal $A\cap B$.

Comment: By distribute, do you mean using the distributive law of sets?

Comment: @auradun Use the fact that $A \cap (B \cup C) = (A\cap B) \cup (A\cap C)$

Comment: In your second given equation (which is really an identity, not an equation), should it be $(A \setminus B)^\complement = A^\complement \cup B$ instead?

Comment: Why on earth did anyone downvote this? From the beginning it was a good question!

Comment: @Arthur Yes, I apologize. I wrote that down wrong. Editing to fix that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See $A\setminus(A\setminus B)$ construction:

[image]

Swap A and B symbols to get essentialy the same result for $B\setminus(B\setminus A)$ hence the equality.

Algebraically the sets' subtraction is equivalent to an intersection with a complement:
$$X \setminus Y = X \cap Y^\complement$$
hence:
$$\begin{align}A\color{green}\setminus(A\color{red}\setminus B) & = A\color{green}\setminus(A \color{red}\cap B^\color{red}\complement) \\
 & = A\color{green}\cap(A \color{red}\cap B^\color{red}\complement)^\color{green}\complement \\
 & = A\cap(A^\complement \cup B) \\
 & = (A\cap A^\complement) \cup (A\cap B) \\
 & = \emptyset \cup (A\cap B) \\
 & = A\cap B
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x, y \in A, B.$ Then, $x,y \not\in A\setminus B$. So, $x,y \in A\setminus(A\setminus B)$.

Above point is symmetric. So, $x,y \in B\setminus(B\setminus A)$.

Next, if $x\in A, x\not\in B$, then, $x\in (A\setminus B)$, giving $x\not\in A\setminus(A\setminus B)$. And similar result we will get for right hand side by symmetry.

Hence,

$A\setminus(A\setminus B) = B\setminus(B\setminus A)\equiv A\cap B$